# How does spring boot application.yml port: ${SERVER_PORT} work

Tags: spring-boot, application.properties

I have seen in Spring boot application.yml as this in working app:-

```
server:
  port: ${SERVER_PORT}
```

It looks like it expect SERVER_PORT from the runtime or for somewher. I was not able to run this app, it fails as:-

Could not resolve placeholder 'SERVER_PORT' in value "${SERVER_PORT}"

It is certianly a working app, I just don't know how to provide this port and run this applicaion. Plase let me know how can I run this app?
Also let me know who this works in spring boot app? Why someone want to use this?

Comment: See here for https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files.property-placeholders

Comment: thx a lot. I didn't find anyhing by Google.